# Have an AppBar that expands and can accommodate a widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am coding an application and I would like to have Google Map in my appbar with the possibility of lowering it by scrolling the AppBar down.

We have tried many things and are staying on the SliverAppBar. First we try with an image. The problem is that the slider area is on the whole screen and we would like it to be only on the AppBar!

Here is our code :

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body:
        NestedScrollView(
           headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return <Widget>[AppBarHomePage()];
          },
           body: Text("Test"),
    ));
  }
}


class AppBarHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const AppBarHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<AppBarHomePage> createState() => _AppBarHomePageState();
}

class _AppBarHomePageState extends State<AppBarHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SliverAppBar(
        expandedHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        floating: true,
        pinned: true,
        snap: true,
        actionsIconTheme: IconThemeData(opacity: 0.0),
        flexibleSpace:  Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  GoogleMapWidget()
                ],
              ),
        );
  }
}
```

[Gif preview here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6kvd.gif)

Answer (score 1):

this solution will helps you to solve the expand app-bar
https://flutterawesome.com/custom-flutter-sliverappbar-behavior/

Comment: I was able to look, but the problem is that we would want an element that does not expand when we are not scrolling over it... Like if we wanted a small curtain at the top that we would come down. Thanks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).